# How to convert NSHTTPURLResponse to String in Swift

Tags: string, swift, xcode6, nshttpurlresponse

I would like to convert my response from the NSHTTPURLResponse type to String:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in 
     println("Response: \(response)")
     var responseText: String = String(data: response, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
})
```

The line below outputs the response message to the console.

```
println("Response: \(response)")
```

But this line renders me an error: Extra argument 'encoding' in Call.

```
var responseText: String = String(data: response, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

How can I successfully convert this "response" into a String?

Comment: The compiler error is confusing. `data` needs to be of type `NSData` but you are passing it an `NSHTTPURLResponse`. The method that is called (and returns a string) is `NSHTTPURLResponse`'s `description` method.

Comment: You probably want to convert `data` to a string, not `response`.

Comment: yes but that isnt the response but a description ;) not good

Comment: I want to use the JSESSIONID found in the response and parse it, then pass it to a new dataTaskWithRequest.

Comment: it is a header field then?

Comment: Yes it is a header field. `headers {
    "Content-Length" = 4730;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1";
    Date = "Sun, 25 Jan 2015 21:25:28 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Set-Cookie" = "JSESSIONID=83A31742591DD2714A090FC53D55EEED; Path=/talkmore3/; Secure; HttpOnly";
}`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### body

grab the data and make it utf string if you want. The response's description is not the response body

```
let responseData = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

#### header field

if you want a HEADER FIELD instead:

```
let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
let field = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["NAME_OF_FIELD"]
```

Comment: note: _parsing_ a description is almost like screen-scraping

Comment: see `let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse` => you have to cast it

Comment: I never intended to grab the data from the body. I was only interested in the header field, which also was included in the response description. However I understand it would be cumbersome to parse the description instead of reading the header field. Marked as the most correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated Answer:**

As is turns out you want to get a header field's content.

```
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    if let sessionID = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["JSESSIONID"] as? String {
        // use sessionID
    }
}
```

---

When you print an object its `description` method gets called.

This is why when you `println()` it you get a textual representation.

There are two ways to accomplish what you want.

1. The easy way

   ```
   let responseText = response.description
   ```

However, this is only good for debugging.

2. The localized way

   ```
   let localizedResponse = NSHTTPURLResponse.localizedStringForStatusCode(response.statusCode)
   ```

Use the second approach whenever you need to display the error to the user.

Comment: he wants the sessionID .. dont get why he should call description or (even more unrelated) NSHTTPURLResponse.localizedStringForStatusCode

Comment: The response-'description' contains http response headers which contain a JSESSIONID I have to parse. edit: If I could access the JSESSIONID directly, that would of course be the optimal solution.

Comment: the description has almost NO use and especially not for parsing data from it

Comment: [response valueForHTTPHeader:] (or what it is called) -- this is simply BAD advice

Comment: @Daij-Djan I changed my answer to reflect the changes. The question did not say anything about a header field, just printing the response.

Comment: yes responseData -- which is also not the response description -- IMO description has NO use except maybe debugging

Comment: @Daij-Djan That's exactly what I wrote 12 minutes ago.

Comment: whatever - I still find it wrong to even write this because it was CLEARLY not the real issue :D (especially no 2) anyway, revoked the vote, ciao

Answer (score 4):

For a newer version in swift

```
   let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse

        let type = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"]
        print("Content-Type", type)

        let l = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Length"]
        print("Content-Length", l)

        if let response = response {   // Complete response
            print(response)
        }


            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the code below, because the response data from your data task is stored in `data`. `response` is the http response, with status codes etc, for more info about http response go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

```
var responseString: String = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the answer json as a string, in Swift 5

```
let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

if let jsonResponse = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    print("JSON String: \(jsonResponse)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It was as simple as `var responseText: String = response.description`.

Comment: as I said, the description is not necessarily the responseData

Comment: I'm actually not looking for the data, or responseData. I need to get the response 'description' as a String that I can parse.

Comment: Apple gives no guarantees about the format of object descriptions (beyond NSString and NSNumber). They are only intended for debugging and subject to change. As such, you do _not_ want to make your app rely on the format of an object's description.