# How do I print the http response to the console in Swift

Tags: json, swift, http

I'm getting an error in Swift that my json response is invalid. I need to find a way to see the raw data being passed back so I can check the values. The error is currently occurring when I serialize the response data.

```
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { urlData, response, reponseError in
        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if res.statusCode == 200 {
                if let _ = urlData {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlData!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141627/how-to-convert-nshttpurlresponse-to-string-in-swift ... in your case convert the urlData to String and log them

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and using the debugger?

Comment: Most likely you get HTML instead of JSON, insert the line `print(String(data: urlData!, encoding: .utf8)!)` before the `do` line. By the way, do not use `NSDictionary` and `.mutableContiners` in Swift and – no offense – `if let _` and then unwrap the optional is pretty silly.

Comment: vadian, this code is about 9 years old. The if used to be the way to verify that the variable had content. What's the modern way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little code snippet that works in Playground. The code should work in your program and, if you are running in the Xcode debugger, you'll see the print output in the console window.

```
import Foundation

let jsonString = #"{ "foo" : "bar }"#
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do
{
    let string = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(string ?? "nil")
    let hex = data.map{ String($0, radix: 16) }.joined(separator: " ")
    print(hex)
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

    print("\(json)")
}
catch
{
    print("\(error)")
}
```

The first two lines just create a data object. You can ignore them because you have your `urlData` from the HTTP response. Note that I have omitted a `"` character from the JSON. This is to cause an error to be thrown when we try to deserialise the data.

The two lines

```
    let string = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("'\(string ?? "nil)'")
```

convert the data into a `String` and then print it. If the result of the `print` is `nil` it means that Swift failed to convert the data into a string using UTF-8. If that's the case, you need to figure out what encoding the response is in.

The next two lines

```
    let hex = data.map{ String($0, radix: 16) }.joined(separator: " ")
    print(hex)
```

produce a hex dump of the raw data (this might produce a very long line for you, so you might want to make it a bit more sophisticated with line breaks). This will only be useful if the string conversion fails and you need to figure out what encoding you have been given.

Finally, we try to convert the data to JSON and print it. The conversion of course fails and throws an exception. So we catch it and print it. In my case, the error thrown pinpoints the problem exactly.

The output in my case looks like this.

```
'{ "foo" : "bar }'
7b 20 22 66 6f 6f 22 20 3a 20 22 62 61 72 20 7d
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unterminated string around line 1, column 10." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unterminated string around line 1, column 10., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=10}
```